# Sorting request response by date and then setting state with it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently have this function:

```
 const fetchJobs = async (userId: string) => {
        setJobs([])

        await axios.post("/api/fetch/fetchMany?type=jobs", {
            user_id: userId
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response == null || response.data.length === 0) {
                setJobs([])
            } else {
                const sortedJobs = response.data.sort = (a: Date, b: Date): Job[] => {
                    return new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate)
                }
                setJobs(sortedJobs)
            } 
        })
    }
```

What it does is fetches a list of 'job' objects, and then attempts to sort them from newest to oldest, before placing them inside of jobs state.

However, there are two issues:

1. I'm getting a 'startDate' does not exist on type 'Date' in the sort function
2. The function is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Job[]>'

For some context, here's my Job type, which is an array of objects:

```
export type Job = {
    _id: string,
    user_id: string, 
    jobTitle: string, 
    employer: string,
    responsibilities: string[], 
    startDate: string | Date,
    endDate: string
}
```

And then here's my state type:

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Job[]>([])
```

I think I need to change what my state can be set as, but I don't understand why I can't set the state using the function, as it returns an array of job types.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type the axios request `await axios.post<Job[]>(...)` so `response.data` is automatically typed accordingly.

[Array#sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a method, not a property. It expects a callback function that recieves two values from the array (which in your case are of type `Job`, not `Date`) and returns a signed number based on their order. Not a boolean.
`response.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate))`

And don't mix `async/await` with `.then()`

so overall

```
const fetchJobs = async (userId: string) => {
  setJobs([])

  const response = await axios.post<Job[]>("/api/fetch/fetchMany?type=jobs", {
    user_id: userId
  });

  if (!response || response.data.length === 0) {
    // setJobs([]) // you've already done that
    return;
  }

  const sortedJobs = response.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate));

  setJobs(sortedJobs);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response - but still not working. It's stating that the a.startDate and b.startDate aren't a number. –

Comment: @JonNicholson sometimes TS is a pain in the ass. TS is annoyed that I do math with Dates, not numbers. Explicit: `(a, b) => new Date(a.startDate).getTime() - new Date(b.startDate).getTime()` or a bit shorter: `(a, b) => +new Date(a.startDate) - +new Date(b.startDate)`

Comment: Spot on - thank you. And you're right, TS is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

For first issue:

> I'm getting a 'startDate' does not exist on type 'Date' in the sort function

You can change types of sorted arguments from

```js
const sortedJobs = response.data.sort = (a: Date, b: Date): Job[] => {
  return new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate)
}
```

to

```js
const sortedJobs = response.data.sort((a: Job, b: Job): number => {
  return new Date(a.startDate).getTime() - new Date(b.startDate).getTime()
})
```

let me know if it fixed second problem, because I can't find problem with:

> The function is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Job[]>'

but it is possible that this change fix both.

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately - I'm getting 'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'' error.

Comment: Sorry, you returning number, not boolean, I fixed in answer

Comment: Appreciate the response - but still not working. It's stating that the a.startDate and b.startDate aren't a number.

Comment: new Date().getTime() instead of new Date() I updated again

Answer (score 2):

#### Use either `async/await` or `Promise` while handling `network tasks`

```
const fetchJobs = async (userId: string) => {
  setJobs([])  //  Initailly set to null

  const response = await axios.post<Job[]>("/api/fetch/fetchMany?type=jobs", {
    user_id: userId
  });

  if (!response || response.data.length === 0) {
    return;    // return here instead of using if/else
  }

  //  Change the sort method by specifying the types
  const sortedJobs = response.data.sort((a: Job, b: Job): number => new Date(a.startDate) - new Date(b.startDate));

  setJobs(sortedJobs); //  set the sorted Jobs here
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response - but still not working. It's stating that the a.startDate and b.startDate aren't a number.

Comment: @JonNicholson right, your types say that the startDate property is either a Date or a string.  If it’s an ISO string (year-month-day) then you should be able to sort those without converting to a Date object.   I would recommend using the lodash sortBy (or orderBy) function to make life easier.  `const sortedJobs = sortBy(response.data, ‘startDate’)`.  That should work if the values are either all string or all Date.  Could be a mess if it’s mixed.